# Error when adding computed index field: InvalidOperationException contextDatabase

Tags: content-search, lucene

I add a custom computed field to the fieldmap node in the Lucene Search config like so:

```
<fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
 <field fieldName="my_field" indexType="UNTOKENIZED" returnType="stringCollection" />
</fieldNames>
```

I also registered my custom computed field like so:

```
<fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
 <field fieldName="my_field" indexType="UNTOKENIZED" returnType="stringCollection">MyAssembly.MyField,MyAssembly</field>
</fields>
```

After saving and building the solution I got this error when logging into Sitecore:

> contextDatabase
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: contextDatabase
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidOperationException: contextDatabase]
>   Sitecore.Forms.Core.Dependencies.DefaultImplItemRepository..ctor(Database
>   contextDatabase, Database masterDatabase) +103

**Further Information:** Sitecore 8.2 update 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what the issue was but in the end to fix this I had to update by field to:

```
<fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
    <field fieldName="my_field" indexType="UNTOKENIZED" returnType="stringCollection" storageType="YES" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
        <analyzer type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
    </field>
</fieldNames>
```

I thought it might be the self-closing tag but I tried just updating that and that that didn't resolve the issue so i'm assuming it is either the settingType attribute or  child node that solved this issue.

If anyone has a better solution please let me know.

Comment: I always thought the analyzer was required along with the other fields you added. Alternatively you can pass a string that is a JSON format. I have done that for things that require a lot of data. Then convert the value. I have an example if you want to go that route.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I saw a few examples without the analyzer so figured it should work but it doesn't seem to. Maybe I'm just missing something else though.